# why it showing unexpected end of file in html code against the doctype command

Tags: html, doctype

It is showing unexpected end of file error in as can be seen in the image itself kindly have a look against the `doctype` command in the udemy code simulator

[image]

Comment: "*The <!DOCTYPE> declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the <html> tag*" http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10924912/1095101

Answer (score 3):

You have the correct doctype: `<!doctype html>` (HTML5 doctype is [case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109157/4206206))
Just remove line 1 from your code; the editor isn't expecting any text before the doctype declaration

Answer (score 1):

The doctype declaration for `HTML5` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

In principle the declaration is case-insensitive.

Conventionally, however, the keyword `DOCTYPE` is always capitalised.

Comment: HTML5 doctype is case-insensitive, this isn't the error

Comment: Fair enough. I am not familiar with the udemy code simulator. I did wonder if it was parsing the declaration too strictly (and throwing an error when it shouldn't have been).

Comment: Ah, that's fair enough